# Converting a set to a vector results in a vector of nested vectors in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

i am fairly new to clojure and would like to know why when i convert a set to a vector, the resultant vector is a vector of nested vectors.

For instance, i have this collection of type Lazy Seq

```clj
(#{:fox :corn} #{:boat} #{})
```

This is as a result of running,

```clj
(map #(disj (set %) :goose :you) [[:fox :goose :corn :you] [:boat] []])
```

I want to loop through the collection and get the vector

```clj
[[:fox :corn] [:boat] []]
```

but the best code i was able to come up with was

```clj
(for [i non-vec] (conj (empty []) (vec i)))
```

where 'non-vec' is the above Lazy sequence.

However running the command produces the following

```clj
([[:fox :corn]] [[:boat]] [[]])
```

which is of type Lazy sequence too.

I would like to know

1: How to get the intended vector

2: Why the output is of type Lazy Sequence while i conjoined it to an empty vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question one:
I think you're looking for

```
(mapv vec '(#{:fox :corn} #{:boat} #{})) ;; [[:fox :corn] [:boat] []]
```

Question two:
I think that's because `for` yields a lazy sequence

Comment: Thank you for this piece of code. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do with list:

```
(map #(remove #{:goose :you} %) [[:fox :goose :corn :you] [:boat] []])
```

If not:

```
(mapv #(into [] (remove #{:goose :you} %)) [[:fox :goose :corn :you] [:boat] []])
```